# can't set HTTP Authorization header on Angular 5?

Tags: angular, http, http-headers

I am working on @angular/http@5.2.6, try to send a GET http request with Authorization header, but on the server side I can't get access the Authorization header.

I used the chrome to debug the GET http header,found the Authorization was set on Access-Control-Request-Headers, as shown below, that is the reason why the server side can't get the Authorization header.

[image]

This is my angular code, but I can't see why it is wrong. Can anyone spot the problem?

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // 获取TOKEN
  getToken() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('auth_token')) {
      console.log(localStorage.getItem('auth_token'),'getToken');
      this.headers = new HttpHeaders({
              'Content-Type': ' application/json',
              'Authorization': 'bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('auth_token')
           });

      console.log('getToken',this.headers);
    }
  }

  get(url?: string) {
    this.getToken();
    return this.http.get(url, { headers : this.headers } ).pipe(catchError(e => this.handleError.bind(this)));
  }
```

Comment: the screenshot looks like the details of a preflight request

Comment: the server allows the CORS for all the domain

Comment: The preflight request will not contain the auth header (by design), it's only sent on the GET.